# Which accounts other than eosio.stake do I need to remove from snapshots to calculate total supply?

Tags: eosio.system

I currently remove eosio.stake from snapshots to calculate the total supply https://www.eossnapshots.io/

There are various EOS system accounts, are there any other I need to remove?

https://www.eoscanada.com/en/what-are-eosio-system-accounts-and-what-do-they-each-do

When adding all the accounts together my sum is roughly 1 billion but CNC lists 900 million as supply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CNC lists **1.006.245.120 EOS** as **Total Supply** and
**906.245.118 EOS** as **Circulating Supply** so your rough 1billion are probably valid for **Total Supply**

Block.one's account with accountname "b1" holds 10% of the initial token-supply but these tokens are locked for 10 years. That's why CMC only shows 900Mil instead of 1Billion.

For the **Total Supply** I wouldn't remove any additional accounts from the snapshot. 
For **Circulating Supply** I would also remove "*eosio.ramfee*", "*eosio.saving*" as these balances are (currently) fully locked, as long as REX is not enabled - and the "b1"-account.
I would assume that CMC is not removing these system-accounts from their calculations so the answer to your question depends on what exactly you want to calculate.